# Sort by ranking algorithm using will-paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm creating a digg-like site using Ruby on Rails that ranks the item (based on [this algorithm](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=231209)). I'm using the will-paginate gem list the items in pages.

The problem is, will-paginate only allows me to insert ':order =>' based on the table data. I would like to make will-paginate to sort by a number which is calculated using a function based on different fields on the table (e.g number of votes, age hours).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the comments/documentation in the code](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb#L38), you can use

```
Post.paginate_by_something
```

in order to use

```
Post.find_all_by_something
```

to get the collection of items you want to use paginate for. The `:order` option is required to set the order of the items.

So for your problem you can create a custom `find` method, adding a rank column using your algorithm. Use the `:order` option to sort on this ranking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `paginate` method on named scopes. If you make a scope for the ordering you could just do `Article.ordered.paginate`.